# OpenCV - Saturated pixels

Tags: opencv, colors, pixel, grayscale

Just like the title of this topic, how can I determine in OpenCV if a particular pixel of an image (either grayscale or color) is saturated (for instance, excessively bright)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, saturated pixels are those associated with an intensity (i.e. either the grayscale value or one of the color component) equal to 255. If you prefer, you can also use a threshold smaller than 255, such as 240 or any other value.

Unfortunately, using only the image, you cannot easily distinguish pixels which are *much too bright* from pixels which are *just a little too bright*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here's what I'm doing: I create an artificial saturated image (for instance, via Photoshop) and I pass it to the program I'm working on. By using OpenCV's minMaxLoc, the highest intensity value within the image is returned. Let's say, for instance, it's 230. If any other pixel within the image has an intensity value equal to 230 or slightly less (for instance, 255), it will be considered saturated. This may not be the best approach, but I'd like to know what you think of it.

Comment: @user3438376 it depends on what you want to do. A value less than 255 (such as 230) is often considered _not saturated_ since it contains "useful" information, on the contrary to 255 which may be a clamped or saturated value. However if you just want to detect white areas, then your approach is good.

Comment: My program deals with a new deblurring technique. The deblurring part works ok, I'm working on saturated pixels handling. Quoting the paper: "Ignoring the data term for these regions while enforcing the regularization term causes the method to perform a simple form of inpainting to improve the fit to the valid measurements".
My program detects saturated pixels (i.e. intensity values of 255) and should be "ignoring the data term while enforcing the regularization term" as stated above. What I'm not sure of is if the program should inpaint the saturated pixels (replace their intensity values...

Comment: ...with the ones of adjacent pixels) or if they will just remain there untouched and their intensity values won't be used during all the calculations to create the unblurred image.

Comment: @user3438376 I would go with the second option: their intensity values won't be used.

Comment: @user3438376 Did you ever finish the deblurring and image saturation program?  Did you publish a paper on it?  I'm exploring a similar problem and would be interested to see where you ended up.